# cmocka, how to check a function pointer

Tags: c, cmocka

I searched in the documentation and in the waiter example but I can't find an example about how to check if the right function pointer is passed as parameter to a function.

This sample code should detail well what I mean:

```
void func_A();
void func_B();

void verify(int value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        process(func_A);
    } else if (value == 1) {
        process(func_B);
    }
}
```

My idea was to mock process like this:

```
void __wrap_process(EVENT_HANDLER handler){
    check_expected(handler);
    ///I made a test also with check_expected_ptr but the result is the same.
}
```

And, in the test call:

```
expect_memory(__wrap_process, handler, func_A, sizeof(func_A));
verify(0);
```

This does not work because if I replace `func_A` with `func_B` in the expect_memory the test pass. I don't see any `expect_*` function other than `expect_memory` that can check a pointer.

What did you use?

EDIT: Added the following example.
EDIT2: Updated example with includes and verified that it compiles correctly.

As example I can provide this simple code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cmocka.h>

union EVENT{
    uint8_t event;
};

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(union EVENT * event);

void wrap_register_callback( CALLBACK callback );

void callback_module_a( union EVENT *event ) {
    //Do something with the event
    //It is out of scope for this test.
    (void)event;
}

void callback_module_b( union EVENT *event ) {
    //Do something with the event
    //It is out of scope for this test.
    (void)event;
}



void __wrap_register_callback( CALLBACK callback ) {
    check_expected(callback);
}

void code_that_set_the_callback( int status ) {
    if (status < 0){
        register_callback(callback_module_a);
    }else{
        register_callback(callback_module_b);
    }
}

void test_correct_handler( ) {
    int status = 0;
    expect_memory(__wrap_register_callback, callback,  callback_module_a, sizeof(CALLBACK));
    //TEST 1 expected result test pass. Result: test pass
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    status = -1;
    expect_memory(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_b, sizeof(CALLBACK));
    //TEST 2 expected result test pass. Result: test pass
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    //At the moment if I change the callbacks in the tests, like:
    status = 0;
    //This is not correct but the test passes.
    expect_memory(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_b, sizeof(CALLBACK));
    //TEST 3 expected result test fail. Result: test pass
    //This is wrong
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    status = -1;
    //This is not correct but the test passes.
    expect_memory(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_a, sizeof(CALLBACK));
    //TEST 4 expected result test fail. Result: test pass
    //This is wrong
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);
}

int main(void)
{
    //Make coverage happy
    const struct CMUnitTest tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(test_correct_handler),
    };
return cmocka_run_group_tests(tests, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Note on the code: The function register_callback is not under the test in this test code. The body of the function is omitted because during the compilation of the code, passing the argument -Wl,--wrap=register_callback to the linker the function is completely replaced with __wrap_register_callback

The idea is that a function initialize a callback, this callback depends on some initialization value. I want to check that the selected callback is the right one depending on the situation.

from the documentation page https://api.cmocka.org/group__cmocka__param.html

the available macros for verify the parameters received by a function that was mocked does not contain a function for verify a function pointer parameter. In my opinion the only function that I can adapt for this scope is expect_memory but

- it is not working,
- I didn't understand correctly the way to use it
- I made a mistake writing the test.

Comment: You should show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated my question with a code example

Comment: The example is an improvement, but is it complete? Admittedly, I am unfamiliar with cmocka, but it does not automatically process source code like this for you, does it? Do not you need to include `<cmocka.h>` and other headers? By entering the example code, you have already fixed one error—the incorrect `sizeof(func_A)` has been replaced by `sizeof(CALLBACK)`. This is one of the points of an MCVE—to eliminate inadvertent errors in stating the question. When you provide an MCVE, other people will be able to examine it in detail. It clears up a lot of communication issues.

Comment: I updated the test code as your request. A couple of comments related to your message: in the explanation of my intent I wrote sizeof(func_A) but in the test code it's written sizeof(CALLBACK). I already tryed to make that substitution. Another test I made was to replace check_expected(callback); with check_expected_ptr(callback); At the end it is a function pointer. In any case the test passes. It should fail because the two last tests must evaluate to false.

Comment: Sorry nobody has answered. I installed cmake and cmocka and gave this a shot. Your source builds with two warnings (line 7: typedef requires a name, and line 35: implicit declaration of function register_callback is invalid in C99), and it fails to link because register_callback is not defined. Changing register_callback to __wrap_register_callback enables building.

Comment: Can you use `expect_value`? cmocka casts the values to some large integer type, so this should work if the C implementation converts pointers to integers without weirdness. It has a `check_expected_ptr` that would seem to be intended to check pointers, but it is mapped to _check_expected and casts the value to an integer anyway, so I do not see the point of it. There is also an `expect_check` for custom checking functions, but it also casts the value to an integer.

Comment: Note that your code includes the comment “This is not correct but the test passes” while it is set to expect `callback_module_b` while `status` is 0. Are you sure that is the right way around? `code_that_set_the_callback` uses `callback_module_b` when `status` is 0, so that expectation is satisfied. When I use `expect_value`, it passes when `callback_module_b` is expected and reports failure when `callback_module_a` is expected, while `status` is 0.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for looking into this. The warning is a typedef without name. I updated it in the code. Regarding the implicit declaration, cmocka states that __wrap_* function are replaced to the original one using the linker. I wrote that yesterday in the note after the sample code in order to clarify that. In cmake a way for passing that argument to the linker is set_target_properties(the_name_of_the_target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--wrap=register_callback")

Comment: Hi again Eric, maybe the misunderstanding is related to the fact that I am not an english native speaker. The "real" test I want to verify is the first part. From //At the moment if I change the callbacks on the two tests must not pass, as they are obvious wrong. But they passes. That is the reason I wrote this question. I am asking a way to make the first two test to pass and the last two to fail. Using the API provided by cmocka I am not able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

cmocka does not appear to have any parameter-checking macro specifically intended for pointers. In many C implementations, `expect_value` may serve your purpose. cmocka converts the value you pass it to `LargestIntegralType`, which it attempts to define to be a wide unsigned integer type. Assuming the type is wide enough, many C implementations will convert different pointers to different integers and equal pointers to equal integers. (Two pointers in C may compare as equal even though they have different bit representations internally. But a good C implementation will normalize the representation when converting to integer.)

If these requirements are met, you should be able to use `expect_value` to test pointers, as with:

```
void test_correct_handler( ) {
    int status = 0;
    expect_value(__wrap_register_callback, callback,  callback_module_a);
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    status = -1;
    expect_value(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_b);
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    //At the moment if I change the callbacks in the tests, like:
    status = 0;
    //This is not correct but the test passes.
    expect_value(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_b);
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);

    status = -1;
    //This is not correct but the test passes.
    expect_value(__wrap_register_callback, callback, callback_module_a);
    code_that_set_the_callback(status);
}
```

Tinkering with the above confirms it is sensitive to whether `callback_module_a` or `callback_module_b` is used. However, the sense of the tests is reversed from what you say in the question: The first two report failure, and the last two report pass. Are you sure you have the tests the right way around? If you swap `callback_module_a` with `callback_module_b` in this code, you will have the situation you request, where the first two pass and the last two fail.